# SSMS Registered Servers with ReadOnly Application Intent

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, ssms, availability-groups

We are working on SQL Server 2014 POC testing with AlwaysOn and one of the user asked about saving the configuration of SSMS with **ReadOnly** Intent using the registered servers in Local server group. This way they don't have to type in the alias name every time they need to access the **ReadOnly** replica.

Unfortunately there is no option within registered servers to add the ApplicationIntent Option unlike the regular object explorer.

I came across this article from Microsoft about changing the connection string in RegSrvr.xml.

https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/786323/ssms-sql-server-management-studio-2012-missing-connection-properties-for-availability-groups

I tried their suggestion and it did not connect to the right replica node when connecting via the local server in the registered servers.

The **ReadOnly** option works fine from object explorer when using the options in the connect window > Additional Connection Parameters. But it does not save the changes made to the connection.

Does anyone know of any alternate solutions on saving the configurations with **ReadOnly** Intent property with SSMS? Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has been fixed in SQL 2016 SSMS when using with registered servers. I was able to register a ReadOnly Intent connection as part of local servers group and open the saved connection for future use. Thanks for the help with this.

Answer (score 5):

**SQL Management Studio (versions prior to 2016)**

Unfortunately, there are some caveats that make using Application Intent in SQL Management Studio somewhat painful:

To connect manually with ReadOnly intent, after bringing up the **Connect 
       to Server** dialog from the Object Explorer, users must remember to:

1. Click **Options >>**.
2. Go to the **Additional Connection Parameters** tab.
3. Enter the additional parameter as ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;
4. (Note: Users must not click the **Options <<** button after entering 
           the Additional Connection Parameters or the parameters will be 
           lost.)
5. Click **Connect**.
6. Always launch query windows by right-clicking on the desired database in the **Object Explorer** view and choosing **New Query** to avoid running into the #3 caveat below.

The caveats that apply are as follows:

1. Although you can get SQL Management Studio to connect with Read Only Intent, it does not store the Additional Connection Parameters when a connection is added to Registered Servers.
2. Behavior when hand editing the locally registered servers in the RegSrvr.xml file to add the Application Intent is extremely inconsistent and will be overwritten any time a change is made through the GUI making this workaround unreliable.
3. The Always On database must be selected before the query window is opened; otherwise, the connection gets routed to the primary server. If you attempt to select the database using the query window's drop down after the query window has already been opened to a non-Always On database, you will get an error dialog. If you try to change the database to an Always On database with a USE statement after the query window has already been opened to a non-Always On database, the results look like this when you attempt to execute the SQL query:

> ```
>       Msg 979, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>       The target database ('AlwaysOnDatabase') is in an availability group 
>       and currently does not allow read only connections. For more 
>       information about application intent, see SQL Server Books Online.
> ```

**SQL Management Studio (versions 2016 or later)**

SQL Server Management Studio 2016 or higher can connect with Read Only Application Intent (using the same 6 steps as prior versions) and it does store the Additional Connection Parameters. There are still some caveats:

1. The Object Explorer view will not enumerate any of the tables or
   other objects in the AlwaysOn databases. Attempting to expand them
   results in an access denied message.
2. You cannot have a Read Only and a non-Read Only connection to the
       same listener open at the same time.
3. Intellisense for object names in the database does not work. (Oddly
       enough, Objects get enumerated just fine in the Query Designer that
       you can launch using **Design Query in Editor...** from the
       right-click menu.)
4. Caveat 3 from the prior versions' caveats still applies.

**Third-Party Products**

[LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) stores the whole connection string including Application Intent and the database when you save a connection and therefore might be a viable option for performing Read Only queries against Always On databases.

Comment: For SSMS 2016+, item 1), this does not seem to be an issue as of SSMS 18.x. I am able to enumerate all objects in the databases fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that you create a configuration file and then you auto create the necessary registered servers in SSMS? Just as mentioned in my MSSQLTips article:

[Automate Registering and Maintaining Servers in SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)](http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3252/automate-registering-and-maintaining-servers-in-sql-server-management-studio-ssms)

Comment: Hi jyao, Thanks for your reply. You have posted an interested powershell script in that article but unfortunately does not work with ApplicationIntent property. I changed the PS to use the following:
New-Item -Name $(encode-sqlname $g.value) -path "sqlserver:\SQLRegistration\$($choice)\$($g.parentfolder)" -ItemType $g.type -Value ("Server=$regsrv ; integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=dbname;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly");

No luck!
   
If this would work, I would have more than happy to use this as an option. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the PowerShell script, but use another spelling (with a space) for application intent? Or have I got the connection methods mixed up?

```
Server=$regsrv ; integrated security=true;Initial Catalog=dbname;
Application Intent=ReadOnly");
```

[Connect to SQL Server Using Application Intent Read-Only](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alwaysonpro/archive/2013/08/02/connect-to-sql-server-using-application-intent-read-only.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment but am adding to DBAUser's answer.

I couldn't see an option to add Application Intent in the GUI when setting up the connection within the registered servers area.

I had to either connect using object explorer (using `Data Source=<Listener>;Initial Catalog=<Database>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`) then register the server once I was connected.

Or add `Initial Catalog=<Database>;ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly` to the connection string in the .regsrvr file.

Comment: You will need to register the readOnly server in the object explorer in order see this as part of the local server groups in the registered servers. In the object explorer, Once you create a readOnly connection to the server with applicationintent, right click on the server and click on Register. Then change the registered Server Name to the one you would like. This will get saved as part of the local servers in the registered servers. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

You may be missing an important part of the puzzle or at least I didn't see it anywhere in your question:

`ApplicationIntent=readonly` is one half of the equation. You also need to pass the parameter `MultiSubnetFailover=True`.

For instance, in the Additional Connection Parameters tab, you want to enter the following:

```
MultiSubnetFailover=True;ApplicationIntent=readonly;
```

Comment: Thanks Tony but this is not the issue I am having.